# Safari negative margin-top

Tags: html, css, safari, margin, text-decorations

I have two values: "price" and "old price". The "old price" should be crossed, but the line should be thinner than it's with `text-decoration: line-through`. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="price">
  <span class="old-price">
    1000
  </span>
  899
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

span.old-price {
    color: #999;
}

span.old-price:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

**Codepen:** [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyJawM)

It works in **Chrome** and **Firefox** as expected:

[image]

But **Safari 8** gives me this:

[image]

What's the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this right now, what version of Safari are you using?

Anyway, you can still use good old absolute positioning:

```
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;

}

span.old-price {
   color: #999;
   position: relative;
}

span.old-price:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
    display: block;

    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/superbiche/pen/QQpbmq

Comment: Thanks, it works! Sorry I didn't mention the version: it's quite old Safari 8 but still in use.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark this answer as the right one. 
Yeah still quite used you're right

Answer (score 0):

This solution seemed not bad:

```
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

span.old-price {
    color: #999;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999 5%, transparent 0%) 0 22px no-repeat;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyJaQe